# Export HyperV VM to Debian Linux share

Tags: hyper-v

I am looking for a solution how to export HyperV VMs to a network share which is provided through a Debian system. 
If I create a SMB share with an authenticated User, I can mount that to the HyperV. 
Read and write works fine, but I cannot export the VM. 
The same result I have if I mount that share through NFS. 

I have search the web but it always lead me in wrong directions... 
Any best practices or hints?

A workaround was to create a VHDX file with residates on that network share and mount that VHDX as an local drive. 
But I am not sure how reliable is a VM export in an VHDX (especially) if I backup that debian aswell.

EDIT: Error messages after export crashed: Request not supported 0x80070032

Comment: **I cannot export the VM** - Why don't you tell us what happens and what messages you get when trying to export the VM so we don't have to guess about what the problem might be.